# Need pageEncoding/charset not to be defined in header (JSP)

Tags: java, jsp

I writing a JSP program that needs to react on an existing program. It gets several variables that the JSP program needs to process and generate a response.

The existing program has his custom headers like:

```
Content-Type: application/x-server-response
```

But the JSP program returns its content with the wrong headers. Like this:

```
Content-Type: application/x-server-response;charset=UTF-8
```

The part thats killing the existing program is the charset. The program requires to get the repsonse with no charset set at all.

I've search the internet for this question and find more people with the same problem but the given results doesn't resolve the problem.

Is it possible to let the JSP program return its content with no charset at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSP creates text output, so the charset has to be added. The JSP behaviour ist correct! It seems to be a wrong implementation of the client using the JSP implemented server! The charset may be ignored, but the implementation seems to have `content-type == "application/x-server-response"` (may be PHP?) instead of parsing the header in a more correct way (see [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) for more information about header formats).

I think you wont get the JSP engine to suppress the charset parameter of the content-type header.

Comment: Is it possible for Java to generate the response of a HTML call without the charset part? Or do I need to change to other language like PHP?

Comment: To implement a server for a non-standard conform client, you need a non-standard conform server implementation. Maybe you find an old servlet container (Tomcat 4.0.4 or older?).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [setContentType](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String))("application/x-server-response").  I haven't tested but that's what the method seems to do.

Comment: What container are you using? I can't reproduce this with Tomcat.